# Java serialization vs Hadoop serialization vs Spark serialization

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, serialization, deserialization

I have worked on `Serialization` and `Deserialization` process of `Java` and trying to understand the same for `Hadoop` and `Spark` also.

Can someone please let me know the difference between Serialization process of `Hadoop`, `Spark` and `Java`.

Comment: please be a little more descriptive. in what contexts did you read `serialization`? can you give a few examples?

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop has its own serialisation interface (Writable), which is designed to make garbage produced as minimum as possible. Objects implementing it are mutable and reused when mapper or reducer is running, bringing amount of garbage further down. Also properly designed Writables can be written by different versions of the code, fixing inherent problem of Serializable.

Spark does not have its own serialisation, and uses native java serialization by default. It is not very performant, and it is possible to make spark to use [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo), which sometimes giving 10x performance gain. However when using Kryo, all custom classes should be registered in SparkConf before running the job.